# Rails Pdf to jpg conversion rendering one image for multiple page pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, rmagick

UPDATE:

In the meantime i switched to the 'rghost' gem which makes use of ghostscript directly and seems to be working very well with pdf's with multiple pages.

I will leave this question open in case someone finds an answer to the problem below.

Here is my problem:

I am using carrierwave and rmagick to convert pdfs into images and it works just fine. The only problem is that when i try to parse a 2..n pages pdf, it always generates an image for the first page and nothing else.

Here are 2 examples of the ways i am handling this:

1. through rmagick:

   ```
   def do_parsing
     pdf_path = "#{Rails.root}/public#{@pdf.pdf.url}"

     raw_pages_arr = Magick::Image.read(pdf_path) { self.density = 400 }

     save_pdf_images(raw_pages_arr)
   end

   def save_pdf_images(raw_pages_arr)
     raw_pages_arr.each do |raw_page|
       page_number = raw_pages_arr.index(raw_page) + 1
       image_name = "#{@pdf.form.name}_page_#{page_number}.jpg"
       raw_page.write(image_name)

       image = File.new("#{Rails.root}/#{image_name}")
       build_pdf_image(image, page_number)
     end
   end
   ```
2. using image magick directly

   ```
   file = Form::Pdf.first.pdf
   file_name = file.path.sub('.pdf', '.jpg')
   system("convert -quality 100 -density '400' #{file.path} #{file_name}")
   ```

In both situations a jpg is created but only for the first page of the pdf, the rest are missing.

One thing i am sure of is that (at least through rmagick) the call to Magick::Image.read(pdf) is resulting in an array with one element regardless of the number of pages the pdf has, so this leaves me scratching my head..

I have been googleing this problem a lot and i can't seem to find someone with a similar issue, everywhere i look everyone is saying that it should automagically convert the pdf to multiple images if it has multiple pages, except it doesn't.

Any ideas would be of tremendous help, maybe i am missing something obvious.

Comment: Is `build_pdf_image`  inbuilt in rmagick?

Answer (score 0):

I've always used ImageList to handle multi-page documents like this:

```
def do_parsing
  pdf_path = "#{Rails.root}/public#{@pdf.pdf.url}"

  image_list =  Magick::ImageList.new(pdf_path) {
    self.density = 400
  }

  save_pdf_images(raw_pages_arr)
end

def save_pdf_images(raw_pages_arr)
  raw_pages_arr.each_with_index do |raw_page, index|
    page_number = index + 1
    image_name = "#{@pdf.form.name}_page_#{page_number}.jpg"
    raw_page.write(image_name)

    image = File.new("#{Rails.root}/#{image_name}")
    build_pdf_image(image, page_number)
  end
end
```

Overall, though, I would recommend using a service for this. There are many intricacies (like color profiles, handling CropBox/BleedBox/ArtBox/TrimBox, alpha channel, etc) of PDF to image conversion and it's a task best left to services that have been doing it for a while. Blitline(http://www.blitline.com/docs/pdf
) is an example of a service that handles these.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although i have tried with ImageList as well with the same result unfortunately.I eventually went with using the rghost gem for this which worked very well. The pdf`s that I am trying to parse are fairly simple forms, nothing special that would include images and all that, so i prefer doing it on the fly rather than using a service for it. But thank you for letting me know there are services out there that can do this, it will most likely be useful on future projects.
Thank you again for taking the time to answer!